# Use index.php for all PHP files that are not found

Tags: nginx

Alright so I've been searching all day for this, and I can't seem to find it.

What I want to happen is let's say I have URL http://example.com/foo.php, and I remove the foo.php file. I want my nginx config to then take the foo.php and pass it as a parameter to http://example.com/index.php

Does anybody know how to do this? I don't really have a preference for the parameter name itself, just that one exists and can be accessed by `index.php`.

Further: I want this to happen nested as well, so if the url is http://example.com/foo/bar/baz.php I would like `/foo/bar/baz.php` to be passed to index.php using something like this: http://example.com/index.php?path=/foo/bar/baz.php

I have fiddled with my site config, and I cannot get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this config:

```
location ~ \.php(/|$) {
  try_files $uri /index.php?q=$uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Nope, that still gives me the file not found. I think because of the catch all PHP.

Comment: Ok, then try with a single location block and `try_files`

Comment: I used a modified version of your original config and got it to throw me a Laravel 404 page. From there I'll be able to do what I need to do.